# Putting "forbidden values" for functions

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I am defining a function $f(x)$ and I would like to put undefined values to some $x$. The point is that if I plot the function I don't want an error to be returned, I want that for all the plotting function I will use, it will "ignore" the $x$ corresponding to forbidden values.

Is there a simple way to do this (i.e not writing 50 lines of functions). Is there a simple keyword for that ?

Comment: [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that Plot ignored values that are not numbers and also suppressed errors. When I try the following:

```
f[x_?(2 <= # <= 4 &)] := 1/0;
f[x_?(4 < # <= 6 &)] := Indeterminate;
f[x_] := x^2;
```

and then

```
Plot[f[x],{x,0,10}]
```

I don't get any errors and the plot ignores x values from 2 to 6.

Comment: Very simple and it works. Thanks. I had examples in which for instance division by zero returned me error in some plots. But I didn't know this keyword indeterminate which looks very usefull.

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues here:

### Defining the function

You could use a `Condition` to prevent the function from evaluating at the forbidden points:

```
forbiddenValues = {1, E, Pi};
forbiddenQ[x_] := Or @@ Table[x == value, {value, forbiddenValues}] // Evaluate;
f[x_] /; !forbiddenQ[x] := x^2
```

```
f /@ {1, 2, E, 4, Pi}
(* {f[1], 4, f[E], 16, f[Pi]} *)
```

### Plotting

From @Natas's comment, use `Exclusions`:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}
  , Exclusions -> forbiddenValues
  , ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}
]
```

[image: Plot with exclusions]

Despite the definition above, you still need to explicitly specify the locations of the exclusions because they do not get detected automatically.
Therefore, if the only goal is to generate a plot with the exclusions, I would not bother with defining the function above. Just plot `x^2` and use the appropriate exclusion options.